# JavaScript file should not get generated if Typescript file has any error

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider below Typescript code

```
class formal
{
    private startString: String = "";
    constructor(startString:String)
    {
        this.startString = startString;
    }

    public sayHello = function() :Number {
       alert(this.startString);
    }     

}

var myIntro = new formal("hello world");
myIntro.sayHello();
```

Currently It has following error
"**A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.
An object that represents a number of any kind. All JavaScript numbers are 64-bit floating-point numbers.**"

But after running tsc command it is generating corresponding js file.
What I need is that it should not generate corresponding JS file until all the errors are resolved of typescript file.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `--noEmitOnError` to your compiler.

It would properly look something like this:
`tsc myFile.ts -w --noEmitOnError`

Comment: If you are interested in other compiler settings, the command `tsc -h` will show all options